# How to update/change one class init arguments by another class?

Tags: python, oop, global-variables, global, python-class

I have two classes which i want to call them **class A** and **class B**; i need to change some init values of class A by class B globally **without making/returning** any new objects from class A (class B should not read main app variables and should not make global variables from them).

**Here is what i did:**

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.blah1_is_beautiful = True
        self.blah2_is_beautiful = True
        self.blah3_is_beautiful = True


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.null_is_null = None

    def change_some_values(self):
        # Class A instance should update here
        A.blah1_is_beautiful = False
        A.blah2_is_beautiful = False
        A.blah3_is_beautiful = False


obj1 = B()
obj1.change_some_values()
# Some codes ...
new_A_class = A()
print(new_A_class.blah1_is_beautiful)
```

But i could not get my expected result.

**Notice:** i do not want to make an object from class A on my main app or call it as global variable in class B and change its instance; Class B should update class A instance by itself without using any outer variables.

**Any help on this is appreciated.**

Comment: Looking at your current example. It seems like you want to change the values of all instances of class A, if class B's change_some_values is called. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: @Hendrik is there anyway that Class B can update class A instance without using outer variables? this is my question

Comment: @Hendrik; Read this scenario: Class A and Class B are from two different modules; Naturally class B dose not know anything about main app variables; so it can not call those variables as global variables. class B only knows the Class A name; just this; can call it; inherited or any kind of these functionalities

Comment: @Hendrik; i guess i need to open new question.

Comment: "only knows the Class A name" so `change_some_values` just knows that there is a class called A, but not the existence of blah123 properties? So what exactly is it updating in class A?

Comment: @Hendrik; Sorry i mixed up your reply with others the solution that you have proposed  is what im looking for thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now your `__init__` method sets the values of your properties to `True` every time the new object is initiated.
In your `change_some_values` method you are only changing the static properties of class A, but aren't using these for anything.
Somethign like this could help you out.

```
class A:
    blah1_is_beautiful = True
    blah2_is_beautiful = True
    blah3_is_beautiful = True

    def __init__(self):
        self.blah1_is_beautiful = A.blah1_is_beautiful
        self.blah2_is_beautiful = A.blah2_is_beautiful
        self.blah3_is_beautiful = A.blah3_is_beautiful


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.null_is_null = None

    def change_some_values(self):
        A.blah1_is_beautiful = False
        A.blah2_is_beautiful = False
        A.blah3_is_beautiful = False


obj1 = B()
obj1.change_some_values()
obj2 = A()
print(obj2.blah1_is_beautiful)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused, you want to change an instance of the class A, or the class itself? To change obj2 this code worked for me:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.blah1_is_beautiful = True
        self.blah2_is_beautiful = True
        self.blah3_is_beautiful = True


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.null_is_null = None

    def change_some_values(self):
        global obj2
        obj2.blah1_is_beautiful = False
        obj2.blah2_is_beautiful = False
        obj2.blah3_is_beautiful = False

obj1 = B()
obj2 = A()
obj1.change_some_values()
print(obj2.blah1_is_beautiful)
```

Notice the change of order when instantiating the classes, otherwise you'll get an "obj2 is not defined" error.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add an extra parameter when calling the function like so:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.blah1_is_beautiful = True
        self.blah2_is_beautiful = True
        self.blah3_is_beautiful = True


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.null_is_null = None

    def change_some_values(self, name):
        name.blah1_is_beautiful = False
        name.blah2_is_beautiful = False
        name.blah3_is_beautiful = False


obj_a = A()
obj_b = B()
obj_b.change_some_values(obj_a)
print(obj_a.blah1_is_beautiful)
```

since the values of self.blah1_is_beautiful are going to be unique for every instance of the class you might want to specify which instances attributes you want to change.

If you want the values to change for all instances of the A class just use :

```
class A:
    blah1_is_beautiful = True
    blah2_is_beautiful = True
    blah3_is_beautiful = True
    def __init__(self):
       pass


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.null_is_null = None

    def change_some_values(self):
        A.blah1_is_beautiful = False
        A.blah2_is_beautiful = False
        A.blah3_is_beautiful = False


obj_a = A()
obj_b = B()
obj_b.change_some_values()
print(obj_a.blah1_is_beautiful)
```

Comment: so do you want to change the T/F value for every instance of the class?

Comment: check my question again

Comment: If you create a new instance of A class after calling change_some_values() there is no way your values will be changed because __init__ function is called when you create an instance of the class. I'm not sure I fully understand what you want to do